# Update Camera Position Using Right Arrow Key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello in my below code i am updating my camera position using UI Buttons which is working fine what i want is to do this same process but by pressing right arrow key  like if i press right arrow key camera will change its position to point A then stops there and when again i press the same arrow key the camera will change its position to point B and as in the code i have a different function to be called on different ui button so on thanks here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cam : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Locations where camera will update its position step by step")]
    public Transform handleview;
    public Transform needle1view;
    public Transform wallview;
    public Transform handletwoview;
    public Transform needle2view;
    public Transform switchview;
    public Transform lastswitchview;

    public GameObject Animatebtn;
    Animator animatebtnanim;

    [Header("UI Buttons")]
    public GameObject inspectionbtn;
    public GameObject animatebtn;
    public GameObject step2btn;
    public GameObject step3btn;
    public GameObject step4btn;
    public GameObject step5btn;
    public GameObject step6btn;
    public GameObject step7btn;

    [Header("Inspection Views")]
    public Transform startview;
    public Transform handle1view;
    public Transform motorview;
    public Transform handle2view;

    [Header("Move Boolean")]
    public bool move = false;

    [Header("Speed At Which Cam Moves")]
    public float speed;

    [Header("Current View/position Of Camera")]
    Transform currentVIEW;

    [Header("Current Angel Of Camera")]
    Vector3 currentangel;

    [Header("FieldofView of Camera ")]
    public float camFieldOFview = 24f;

    public int track = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Camera.main.fieldOfView = camFieldOFview;
        animatebtnanim = Animatebtn.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (move)
        {
            //float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            //transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, currentVIEW.position, step);
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, currentVIEW.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
            currentangel = new Vector3(Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, currentVIEW.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, Time.deltaTime * speed),
                Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, currentVIEW.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Time.deltaTime * speed),
                Mathf.LerpAngle(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z, currentVIEW.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z, Time.deltaTime * speed));

            transform.eulerAngles = currentangel;
        }

        //if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        //{
        //    if (track == 7)
        //        track = 1;
        //    if (track == 1)
        //    {
        //        moveTOstartVIEW();
        //        move = true;
        //    }
        //    else if (track == 2)
        //    {
        //        moveTOhandleONEview();
        //        move = true;
        //    }
        //    track += 1;

        //}

    }
    // this function will lerp camera to startview location
    public void moveTOstartVIEW()
    {
        currentVIEW = startview;
        move = true;
    }

    public void moveTOhandleONEview()
    {
        currentVIEW = handle1view;
        move = true;
        animatebtnanim.SetBool("start", true);
        animatebtnanim.SetBool("move", false);
    }

    public void moveTOmotorview()
    {
        currentVIEW = motorview;

        move = true;
    }


    public void moveTOhandleTWOview()
    {
        currentVIEW = handle2view;
        move = true;
    }

    public void Handleview()
    {
        currentVIEW = handleview;
        inspectionbtn.SetActive(false);
        animatebtn.SetActive(false);
        move = true;
    }

    public void Needleoneview()
    {
        currentVIEW = needle1view;
        step2btn.SetActive(false);
        move = true;
    }

    public void Wallview()
    {
        currentVIEW = wallview;
        move = true;
        step3btn.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void Handletwoview()
    {
        currentVIEW = handletwoview;
        move = true;
        step4btn.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void Needletwoview()
    {
        currentVIEW = needle2view;
        move = true;
        step5btn.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void Switchview()
    {
        currentVIEW = switchview;
        move = true;
        step6btn.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void lastSwitchview()
    {
        currentVIEW = lastswitchview;
        move = true;
        step7btn.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it already works with the UI, then just call the same function when you hit the right arrow.

Comment: @Eddge i have different function for every button

Comment: Then keep a tracker of where you are, set that value, and use a switch statement to call the corresponding function for which button would have been hit.

Comment: @Eddge sir can u please modify my code to what you are telling becuase i am noob please if u have time thanks

Comment: How about you give it a try, and then if you need help show what you tried.

Comment: @Eddge ok i will try then tell u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you have a usual `UI.Button` component and now want to do the same thing on a certain keyboard key as this button would do in `onClick`.

#### Solution 1: Extending the Button

I would simply invoke the Button's [`onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) event after getting a certain [`KeyCode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html) by putting the following component right next to the `Button` component on your button objects (**not on the camera**)

```
using UnityEngine;

// make sure you are not accidentely using 
// UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.Button
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class KeyboardButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Which key should this Button react to?
    // Select this in the inspector for each Button
    public KeyCode ReactToKey;
    private Button _button;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _button = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    // Wait for the defined key
    private void Update()
    {
        // If key not pressed do nothing
        if (!Input.GetKeyDown(ReactToKey)) return;

        // This simply tells the button to execute it's onClick event
        // So it does exactly the same as if you would have clicked it in the UI
        _button.onClick.Invoke();
    }
}
```

---

#### Solution 2: Replacing the Button

Alternatively if you do not want to use a `Button` anymore at all you can add your own [UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) e.g. `OnPress` to the above script instead

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class KeyboardButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Which key should this Button react to?
    // Select this in the inspector for each Button
    public KeyCode ReactToKey;

    // reference the target methods here just as 
    // you would do with the Button's onClick
    public UnityEvent OnPress;

    // Wait for the defined key
    private void Update()
    {
        // If key not pressed do nothing
        if (!Input.GetKeyDown(ReactToKey)) return;

        OnPress.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply as u see in my code that i have so many public functions for moving my camera from one position to another position and currently i am doing this using ui buttons of unity like if i have 6 public functions then i also have 6 ui buttons now i want to do same thing using rightarrow button from the keyboard shortly i want to call those public functions step by step using rightarrow button from keyboard thanks and i will try this too

Comment: currently i have attached my script to my main camera now where should i attach this script that you provided

Comment: As I told you you should put it on a button next to the `Button` component

Comment: please also see my alternative you should use if you want to get completely rid of the Buttons

Comment: hello i am getting null reference exception at last line of your code here " _button.onClick.Invoke(); "

Comment: Then either the script is not placed on a GameObject with a `Button` component or the Exception comes actually from a call in onClick

Comment: i attached this script to a button

Comment: Glad to help :)